# ssh_config host not connecting, connects otherwise, why?

Tags: ssh

Here's my ssh config:

```
Host example.com
    HostName [IP]
    Port 2216
    User centos
Host example-two.com
    HostName [IP]
    Port 2216
    User centos
```

But when trying to ssh example-two.com it times out:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\{{user}}/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\{{user}}/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for example-two.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname [IP] is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [IP] port 2216.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:0000020694DA5A60
debug1: connect to address [IP] port 2216: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host [IP] port 2216: Connection timed out
```

However doing:

```
ssh user@ip -p 2216
```

works without a hitch. I thought Host was a tag and HostName was what mattered, but for what it's worth example-two.com doesn't point anywhere and that's the only apparent difference I can tell.

Comment: Should the last command use port 2216?

Comment: Everything should use 2216. The last command actually reads: debug1: Connecting to {{IP}} [{{IP}}] port 2216, before finish_connect - ERROR. Connecting to the first domain, output is identical and it works, so I'm not really sure what's going on.

Comment: Yeah I don't believe it I was using two numbers and reading them as one, problem solved thank you Andrew!

Comment: @matt, do you still remember what was the issue ? I am facing the similar problem during the ssh connect.